# .git/hooks/pre-commit: line 92: 18278 Segmentation fault: 11 ${CMD}

Tags: git

Getting Error while committing the code:

The error code is:

`.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 92: 18278 Segmentation fault: 11  ${CMD}`

.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 92: 18278 Segmentation fault: 11  ${CMD}

Comment: your git pre comit hook is segfaulting. What is done in .git/hooks/pre-commit ?

Comment: In case by mistake if I have done anything wrong with the  git/hooks/pre-commit.  I have just deleted the old .git folder from the local project and added new .git folder from freshly cloned repository. but still I'm getting mentioned issue. @OznOg

Comment: git has hooks ([git help githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)) and apparently your pre-commit hook triggers a segfault. Do you need more guidance about hooks ?

Comment: As a side node, you do not commit to github....you commit _locally_ and this is where it is failing.

Comment: So, what command did you run on line 92 of your pre-commit hook? That's where the problem is. This has nothing to do with Git itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the issue in talisman. You can refer this [talisman issue](https://github.com/thoughtworks/talisman/issues/401)